# using app.use and express.static to retrieve an html file from public folder

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am working on my first node/express project, and I am having difficulty with the express.static function within .use. I have explored all the documentation and with my beginner mind it is a bit too abstract apparently for me to apply to this, but with all of the different solutions I have tried it always returns 404 not found.

file structure:

```
 Project
 |
 +-- index.js
 +-- package.json
 |    
 +-- public
 |  |  
 |  \-- documentation.html
```

[image]

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
//this is not working
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I have also tried

```js
app.use('/documentation.html', express.static('public))
```

as well as trying to use `path.join` to specify the file path.

I have verified I have the correct version of express and node.

Not sure how to proceed

```js
// this all works
let topMovies = [array that is working]
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to my movie list!')
});
app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
    res.json(topMovies)
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Your app is listening on port 8080.')
})
```

I expected writing `localhost:8080/documentation.html` to return my html file, and it said `404 not found`.

Comment: Where exactly in your file system is `documentation.html` and where in your file system is index.js?  We need to know the relative location of the two in your file system.  Please show the hierarchy.

Comment: While it's not conventional to serve your html files like that simply using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` should allow you to navigate to `localhost:8080/documentation.html` no problem. Restart your server and check for spelling/typo issues.

Comment: yeah i dont know, i have restarted the server and checked for typos... it works with the normal .get method. I am really not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a route handler for `/documentation` (or `/documentation.html`):

```
app.get("/documentation", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/documentation.html"));
});
```

This will take all GET request and return the file from the filesystem.

The middleware `app.use` and Express static methods can also be removed.

express.static is best used when you are serving a larger number of files that all have the same URL prefix (i.e. `/js/*.js` or `/docs/*.html`).

Comment: this works to serve the documentation.html file, ideally my program wants me to use express, as opposed to the conventional get request so i can familiarize myself with express, but thank you I am using this as a stop gap